# What is this ("frequent vibrato") vocal technique called?

Tags: voice, terminology

What is this vocal technique called and any hints/links on how to master it?

Here is one example:

It sounds like a frequent type of vibrato. But searching web for "vibrato" ends up in the lessons for "less frequent" vibrato (like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:VIBRATO.ogg). Searching for "frequent vibrato" doesn't give good result either.

So maybe this vocal technique has its own name and I'll be glad to know it.
Thank you!

Comment: I think we call that a "fast vibrato" not a "frequent vibrato".

Comment: I don't hear a lot of difference between the woman in the video and the wikipedia clip.  But if you want to sound like the woman in the video, I think you can get that by pushing your voice and not using good breath support.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's just a vibrato, and this fast type is a style. A fast vibrato seems to be fairly popular in traditional popular songs. Try France, Italy, some Baltic countries. I associate this with 40s-late 60s. For the French origin, I suggest you to look up "modern chanson" as a genre, as this fast vibrato with a dramatic force in the voice is quite popular there. Edith Piaf is probably the most known chanson singer of all time. Italy and Baltic countries have their own equivalents of the genre, but unfortunately I still haven't been able to find out what the country-specific terms for the genre are. Italians may simply call it "canzone", or (in everyone's own language), "popular songs" (with referral to a specific time when this was pop).

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of Russian singing, is it not? (I can't read Cyrillic). It is not a vocal style with which I'm familiar.

However, the practice of using a good deal of vibrato is one component of the vocal technique and style of singing called [*bel canto*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bel_canto) (that is an Italian term) used in Western European operatic singing and taught to young singers in university music schools around the world.

This video example of yours is *not* an example of *bel canto* technique *per se*; what I mean to say is that if you look up references to [*bel canto*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bel_canto) technique, it will have information about using lots of vibrato in singing.